# Add customer email in a text on WooCommerce Order received page

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce, on top of my thank you / order-received page, I've added a custom text, with the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_order_received_text', 1, 0);
function my_order_received_text(){

    echo '<div class="my_thankyou2"><p>' . __('Your download link was sent to: ') . '</p></div>' ;

}
```

How can I get the email address of the customer added to the end of the custom text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To get **the customer billing email**, you can use one of those:
>
> - The Woocommerce `WC_Order` method [`get_billing_email()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_get_billing_email)
> - The WordPress function [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) with the meta key `_billing_email`  from order ID.

Now you can set the text in **2 different locations**:

**1) On top of Order received page:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'my_order_received_text', 10, 2 );
function my_order_received_text( $text, $order ){
    if( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
        return $text;
    }
    // Get Customer billing email
    $email = $order->get_billing_email();

    return $text . '<br>
    <div class="my_thankyou2"><p>' . __('Your download link was sent to: ') . $email . '</p></div>' ;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**2) On bottom of Order received page:**

Using the `WC_Order` method [`get_billing_email()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_get_billing_email) this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_order_received_text', 10, 1 );
function my_order_received_text( $order_id ){
    if( ! $order_id ){
        return;
    }
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
    $email = $order->get_billing_email(); // Get Customer billing email

    echo '<div class="my_thankyou2"><p>' . __('Your download link was sent to: ') . $email . '</p></div>' ;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Alternatively, using WordPress [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function, replacing in the function:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
$email = $order->get_billing_email(); // Get Customer billing email
```

By the following line:

```
$email = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_email', true ); // Get Customer billing email
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm learning so much, because of your woocommerce code answers and explanations. thanks!

Comment: for 1) why is the line if( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order' ) { return $text; .... important? "if it's not an order than do nothing" or what does it mean?

Comment: @mika2019 Just to be sure that we don't get the WC_Order Object "null" with a displayed error.

Comment: for case 1) oh, I'm getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ect... for the following line: if( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order' ) {

Comment: @mika2019 Sorry I forgot a closing rounded bracket.… Updated…