# Append a text to total price only in Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I have the following code that adds suffix text in the total section of BOTH cart and checkout pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_total', 'custom_total_message' );
function custom_total_message( $price ) {
    $msg = 'Prices for grocery items may vary at store. Final bill will be based on store receipt.<br />';

    return $price . $msg;
}
```

However, I only want the suffix text to display ONLY in the checkout but not cart page.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I would avoid modifying the price this way, maybe something like `add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_total_message')` would be more appropriate. I've used this before for things like `"please allow 14 days for order processing" type messages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use [Woocommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) to restrict the display on checkout page only…

Now you should better use the following hook instead, to avoid problems, melting float numbers with stings on total amount:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'custom_total_message_html', 10, 1 );
function custom_total_message_html( $value ) {
    if( is_checkout() )
        $value .= __('Prices for grocery items may vary at store. Final bill will be based on store receipt.') . '<br />';

    return $value;
}
```

Or even better on a separate table row after the total, using this instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'review_order_after_order_total_callback' );
function review_order_after_order_total_callback(){
    $text = __('Prices for grocery items may vary at store. Final bill will be based on store receipt.');

    ?><tr class="order-total"><th colspan="2"><?php echo $text; ?></th></tr><?php
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

---

If you decide to keep your initial hook, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_total', 'custom_total_message', 10, 1 );
function custom_total_message( $price ) {
    if( is_checkout() )
        $price .= __('Prices for grocery items may vary at store. Final bill will be based on store receipt.') . '<br />';

    return $price;
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Untested.

Comment: Question - how would I add the same message but to the Order Received/Thank you page?

Comment: @Les Where in order received? Se this answer related thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/55131790/3730754